# Fliped rows order from Importrange in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, reverse

I have data to import from google sheet that are random and I need to get it in reversed row order using importrange function in another sheet?
The formula needs to be flexible as the row number in imported range may vary.

Can you help me to find solution? I was looking for Query parameters but I found only desc/asc parameter which is not helpful in this case. I can't make any "helping" column in this sheet.

[image]

Sample sheets:
importrange source sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc/edit#gid=0

importrange target sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xXHea0yS9dEEBhYVongjDcg6jRptWFLjvL9C3T_hwMw/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: I added samle sheets in post above

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({IMPORTRANGE("id", "sheet1!A2:C7"), 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(IMPORTRANGE("id", "sheet1!A2:C7")))}, 4, 0), 9^9, 3)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(SORT({
 IMPORTRANGE("1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc"; "Plan dnia!A2:M700")\ SEQUENCE(ROWS(
 IMPORTRANGE("1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc"; "Plan dnia!A2:M700")))\TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IMPORTRANGE("1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc"; "Plan dnia!A2:M700"));;9^9)))}; 14; 0); 
 "where Col15 is not null"; 0); 9^9; 13)
```

[image]

Comment: I got error. Maybe the case is range which is different in my final sheet than in given example. In fact it's : "Plan dnia!a2:m700"

Comment: @MichałKostrzewa answer updated. see your target sheet

Comment: I don't know if two importRange calls are less efficient than this:
=let(r, IMPORTRANGE("id", "sheet1!A2:C7"),
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  SORT( {r, SEQUENCE(ROWS(r))} , 4, 0),
 9^9, 3))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=SORT({ARRAYFORMULA(row(indirect("A1:A"&(counta(importrange("id","A1:A")))))),
query(importrange("id","A1:E"),"where Col1 is not null")},1,0)
```

if you begin at line 2

```
=SORT({ARRAYFORMULA(row(indirect("A2:A"&(1+counta(importrange("id","A2:A")))))),
query(importrange("id","A2:E"),"where Col1 is not null")},1,0)
```

Comment: I got error. Maybe the case is range which is different in my final sheet than in given example. In fact it's : "Plan dnia!a2:m700"

Comment: I have updated my answer (by adding 1) to begin in row #2

Comment: Can't make it :/ Can you please paste it in real sheets? - Data source https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FbovD-T1ickPSat-RFsz_lk-HWZw6Ge-B87A4vhwLZc/edit?usp=sharing - Target sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xXHea0yS9dEEBhYVongjDcg6jRptWFLjvL9C3T_hwMw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, it is because there are blank values inside a column

Comment: the simpliest solution could be `=sort({ARRAYFORMULA(row(A2:A6))\importrange(U1;"A2:E6")};1;0)`